# take sample form streaming dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to apply a function (which works with regular spark dataframes) to streaming data. Before I apply this function I need to use .rdd.takeSample() on the given data but of course this doesn't work with streaming dataframes.

I get my streaming data using the following structured streaming code:

```
dsraw = spark \
            .readStream \
            .format("kafka") \
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "192.168.99.100:9092") \
            .option("subscribe", "topic") \
            .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
            .load()

ds = dsraw.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

My data is a set of random numbers, in the form {'number': 1}, etc. Ideally, I want to put all the nubmers read from this stream into a dataframe and return it.

Is there a way to convert a streaming dataframe to a spark dataframe or an rdd? If not, is there an alternative method for takeSample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to write the streaming data into the memory,
then create dataframe/rdd using `spark sql`:

```py
dsraw = spark \
            .readStream \
            .format("kafka") \
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "192.168.99.100:9092") \
            .option("subscribe", "topic") \
            .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
            .load()

ds = dsraw.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")

kafka_value_df = ds.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
output_query = kafka_value_df.writeStream \
                      .queryName("numbers") \
                      .format("memory") \
                      .start()
output_query.awaitTermination(10)

value_df = spark.sql("select * from numbers")  # df

value_rdd = value_df.rdd  # rdd
```

I don't know exactly what format your original data is (just `{'number': 1}` is not enough information), you might have to use `map` or `json.loads` depend on your data to get the desired format for the df/rdd.